# how to connect flutter app with nodejs locally with real device

Tags: node.js, flutter, localhost

I want to connect my flutter app to node server locally through my real device.I have seen many solution but still didn't get any clear picture.can anyone elaborate the steps to connect

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be helpful if you could explain at which point you got stuck. Maybe [this](https://medium.com/@suragch/minimal-client-server-example-for-flutter-and-node-js-3e1b376f1093) will help you ...

Answer (score 1):

you have two ways to do that:
1- if your mobile and computer - which contain (node.ja and database) - connected at same wifi, so, you should just go to CMD in your computer and type (ipconfig) and try to find the ipv4 for (wireless) or wifi, after that just in your mobile you can access the api by just replace (localhost) or (127.0.0.1) with your local ip which your found in cmd.....

or if you don't using wifi, you can just run your mobile hotspot, and connect your laptop with it by wifi, and also follow same steps as above...

Answer (score 0):

Device must be able to connect to localhost:<port> but to make this happen connect your mobile to computer via usb or connect over same wifi connection.

After this hit **chrome://inspect/#devices** and port forward localhost: to  so now you can easily connect to localhost:<port> on your mobile phone.

Refer to image below and for more details check out the insightful medium blog by Neeraj Moudgil

[image]

https://medium.com/@neerajmoudgil/how-to-test-localhost-node-apis-on-android-device-253fcdd32c18